# Single endpoint for ingoing mail with multiple purposes

Tags: php, laravel

The following code is not one of my proud moments. In its initial state, I had only a single purpose, but know I'm up to three purposes and I don't know if it would stop there.

I'm using [mailin.io](http://mailin.io) to forward mails to my endpoint as JSON data.

There are three main purposes, I've tried to describe it as best as I could as comments in the code. The code is messy and unclean and I would appreciate some pointers on how I can structure it better.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Conversation;
use App\Jobs\SendSurveyEmail;
use App\Message;
use App\Score;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Mailcatcher extends Controller
{
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('mailinMsg')) {
            $msg = $request->get('mailinMsg');

            $msg = json_decode($msg);

            $address = $msg->to[0]->address;
            $name = $msg->to[0]->name;

            $parts = explode("@", $address);

            if ($parts[1] != "example.com") {
                // If the mail is not meant for my app, but I'm receiving because my app is a BCC recipient
                $this->_sendSurvey($msg);
            } else {
                // If the mail is meant for my app

                // Check if I'm using an alias (for unsubscrubing)
                $key = $parts[0];
                $key_parts = explode("+", $key);

                if (count($key_parts) > 1) {

                    // Unsubscring the sender (just logging currently)
                    if ($key_parts[0] == "unsub") {
                        Log::info('Survey Unsubscribe: ' . $key);
                    }

                } else {


                    // If the mail is meant to be a part of conversation and if so, store a new
                    if ($conversation = Conversation::where('key', $key)->first()) {
                        $content = $msg->text;

                        if (empty($content)) {
                            if (!empty($msg->html)) {
                                $content =  $msg->html;
                            } else {
                                // Don't do anything since the mail content is empty
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        $message = new Message();
                        $message->conversation_id = $conversation->id;
                        $message->user_id = 0;
                        $message->name = $msg->from[0]->name;
                        $message->email = $msg->from[0]->address;
                        $message->content = $content;
                        $message->save();
                    } else {
                        dd("I have no idea why I'm receiving this mail");
                    }
                }


            }

        }

        return response(null, 200);

    }

    private function _sendSurvey($msg)
    {
        // Sending a survey to a user

        $units = [
            'm' => 60,
            'h' => 60 * 60,
            'd' => 60 * 60 * 24,
            'w' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        ];

        $address = $msg->to[0]->address;
        $name = $msg->to[0]->name;

        foreach ($msg->envelopeTo as $envelope) {
            list($key, $domain) = explode("@", $envelope->address);

            if ($domain == "example.com") {
                if ($mailcatcher = \App\Mailcatcher::where('key', $key)->first()) {

                    // Make sure that the application is still active
                    if ($application = $mailcatcher->application) {
                        $score = new Score([
                            'name' => $name,
                            'email' => $address,
                        ]);

                        $application->scores()->save($score);

                        $delay = $mailcatcher->delay * $units[$mailcatcher->units];

                        $job = (new SendSurveyEmail($application, $score))->delay($delay);
                        $this->dispatch($job);

                        $mailcatcher->hits++;
                        $mailcatcher->save();
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }


        }
    }

    public function checkin(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request);

        return response(null, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful? I gave you the review you requested but got no feedback from you, positive or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably shouldn't be doing the work in this script. I'd have a `MailParser` or `MailTriage` class that does nothing except receive the request, figure out what it's about and forward it to the appropriate service.
2. I'd have one service for each task: add to conversation, send survey, unsubscribe...
3. Because email addresses are case insensitive, I would make sure that all checks are case insensitive.

I would replace...

```
if ($parts[1] != "example.com")...
if ($key_parts[0] == "unsub")...
if ($conversation = Conversation::where('key', $key)->first()...
...
```

...with equivalents that would match whether the email is lower, upper or mixed case. The simplest way is to lowercase the address before you do any processing.

```
$address = strtolower($msg->to[0]->address)
```

This way you only have to worry about matching against a lowercase string

Comment: Thank you for your input, some great points and it makes sense to try and put the responsibility of parsing the mail in a separate class.